# Activating conda environment with its full path

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Usually, we activate a conda environment with the command:

```
source activate env_name
```

Is it possible to activate conda environment with its full path? For example:

```
source (fullpath)/bin/activate
```

When I do this it activates the default environment of anaconda i.e the root environment.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Update for conda 4.4 and up:**

You need to specify the conda environment path to activate. The new `conda activate` command should not need the full path to an "activate script" any longer, since the command is now "built-in" to conda. So something like:

```
conda activate (fullpath)/env-name-here
```

should work.

---

The command you have specified activates the `root` environment because you have not given conda an environment to activate, and `root` is the default. If you want to activate a particular environment, you can certainly do so with the full path to the `activate` script, for instance

```
source (full path to main Anaconda directory)/bin/activate (fullpath)/env-name-here
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                           You're missing this part
```

Comment: Grr has it right. The full path goes in the <env-name-here> as opposed to be in the activate command.

Comment: Hmm... what if the `activate` script isn't on your PATH? Possibly you need the full path to the activate script and the full path to the environment.

Comment: You could potentially rephrase it as source (fullpath)/env-name-here/bin/activate (fullpath)/env-name-here.

Comment: @Pierre-LucBertrand I think the `activate` script should still be from the main Anaconda/Miniconda directory. Also, one should no longer use the `source` method, the new method (with conda 4.4) is `conda activate` which means you definitely don't need the path to the activate script, since the `activate` command is built-in to conda now

Comment: Sometimes, `source (fullpath)/bin/activate` mentioned by the OP does work if there is an `activate` script in the environment folder. For example, when using [conda-pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) for environment moving, one can use `source my_env/bin/activate` to activate the environment (see [here](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/#commandline-usage)). Of course, `conda activate ./my_env` can also be used.

Answer (score 11):

You can activate an environment that is not in your conda environment list by passing the path to the environment. For example you can create an environment in any directory you want with the `-p` argument. Like so:

```
conda create -p /path/to/some/location/mytestenv/ python=3.5
```

This will **NOT** show up in `conda env list`, but you can activate it with:

```
source activate /path/to/some/location/mytestenv
```

Comment: Not sure when it changed, but this definitely will show up in `conda env list` unless one is manipulating the `~/.conda/environments.txt` that Conda uses to track unnamed environments.

Comment: It shows up in the list, but doesn't have a name and requires full/relative path for activation

Answer (score 0):

yes, it does activates the default environment of anaconda.

you can see the list of created or available environments by :

```
conda env list
```

don't understand, what was the answer you were looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is a old question but writing the answer for folks returning to this page. When you create a conda environment with the prefix, you'll not be allowed to give it a name. Please follow the below steps so that you'll have name for your conda environment and can activate it directly by using the name rather than the full path.

1. Navigate to the custom folder where you want to create the new environment.
2. D:\condaEnvs>conda create --prefix=FastAI --> This creates a conda environment named FastAI
3. D:\condaEnvs> conda config --append envs_dirs ‘D:\condaEnvs\FastAIEnv’ --> This will give a name to your newly created conda environment.

With the new versions of conda, we dont have this issue anymore.