# How to fix: Conda activation is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, command-prompt, conda

installed Python 3.7.3 and Anaconda and tried to activate it in the Anaconda Prompt.

```
activate %PATH%
```

but i get the error

```
activate does not accept more than one argument
```

What can I do about it ?

Comment: Why you're passing your PATH variable to the activate command? you shall pass the conda.sh path to that.

Comment: So I tried :   activate C:\Users\Ich\Anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh   .But then i get the error "Not a conda environment"

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't quite understand how conda works.

In conda, you need to first create your own environment. In this case, let's call it `my_env`.

```sh
conda create -n my_env python
```

Then, you can activate that environment with

```sh
conda activate my_env
```

Also, pay attention that the `conda` precedes the activate, using `activate` directly is obsolete.

Comment: Wow it does downloading packages right now. Hope this will help. Thanks Mate !

Comment: Did it work? If so, I would appreciate if you would mark this answer as correct.

Comment: yes. How can I mark this as correct ? (sorry I am completely new)

Comment: There should be a check mark button below the upvote/downvote buttons for you. Should turn green if you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **space** in `path`, please try this

`activate "C:\Users\USER\New Project\"`

Generally you have to specify the conda env full path. 
[image]

Comment: same error "activate does not accept more than one argument ..."

Comment: I generally activate conda using full path .

have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929791/activating-conda-environment-with-its-full-path

Comment: I have added a photo in edited answers. it works for me

Comment: You only have to specify the full path if you don't use the default path. Otherwise you can just have the environment name as argument.

Comment: For demonstration I have showed you this image. But, in my work I have three servers, and a common shared filesystem. In that file system I keep my conda environment. when I try to access from other two server, I have no options to add  `short environment name`, but `full path`. The other two server has only conda installed, but no information about the conda environment in the shared folder.  I activate using full path.

Comment: I don't think conda is meant to share environments between machines ... It only works if the different machines have the *exact* same setup. Isn't the beauty of conda that you can reproduce the same environment without needing a shared folder?

Answer (score 0):

yes writing your argument in a closed quote worked for me if there is a space in between characters. So here's what I did with my issue:

```
>>> conda activate "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\sample_project_1\env"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Linux** you can start conda with command (assuming that conda was installed @ `~/miniconda3/`)

```
source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate
or
source [conda_install_path]/bin/activate 
or
source [conda_install_path]/bin/activate base
```

By default, `(base)` virtual environment is loaded.
You can switch to a different environment by

```
conda activate [env_name]
```

A sorter path is to type directly

```
source [conda_install_path]/bin/activate [env_name]
```

As usual, you can avoid re-typing activation commands every time by augmenting the .bash_rc script