# How to change path to anaconda environment?

Tags: python, linux, database

I'm currently working on a linux server with anaconda installed. When I type

`which conda`, I get a path

```
abc/xyz/qrs/miniconda3
```

I want to change this to

```
srt/xyz/qrs/miniconda3
```

how do I do this?

I have tried setting:

```
export ANACONDA_PATH="/srt/xyz/qrs/miniconda3"
```

I have also tried vim ~/.condarc but it is a blank file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing it in with the path (-p) parameter?

relevant post: [Activating conda environment with it's full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929791/activating-conda-environment-with-its-full-path)

Comment: I used my .bashrc and got this to work. Would you mind upvoting my question? I'm new here and this would help me a lot!. Thanks!