# Activate conda environment situated outside the default folder

Tags: python, anaconda

I have no access to the folder with Anaconda environments on some pc.
Can I temporarily set the environment path to be different from the default one?

UPD:
I've tried `conda activate ./Desktop/My_env`
And it is ok. But when I'm trying to launch the jupyter notebook I get the error:

```
-bash: /home/username_on_the_other_pc/My_env/bin/jupyter: /home/my_local_pc_I_have_rights_to/anaconda3/envs/My_env/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929791/activating-conda-environment-with-its-full-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activating conda environment with its full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929791/activating-conda-environment-with-its-full-path)

Comment: Sounds like 1) original question has been answered 2) you're changing the question. Also, Jupyter + Conda has been exhaustively addressed on here, so please try searching first.

Comment: yes, there emerged different problem related to jupyter and environment not just activation of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on linux or mac .. just try `source path/bin/activate`. It should activate the environment. Let us know if you have any issues with that command.

Comment: Thanks, `source anaconda/bin/actvate my_env` works for me